# Why are URLs not getting linkified when enclosed in Html.fromHTML() in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, linkify, html.fromhtml

I have the following code executed in onBindViewHolder() of a RecyclerView:

```
    String commentPrompt = "<html><b>" + ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).comment.getText().toString() + "</b></html>";
    TextView commentText = new TextView(context);
    commentText.setText(item.comment);
    Linkify.addLinks(commentText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

    if (!item.comment.contains("www.") || item.comment.contains("https://")) {
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).comment_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(commentPrompt + BLANK + item.comment, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
    } else {
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).comment_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(commentPrompt + BLANK + commentText.getText(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
    }

    ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).comment_text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The problem is that when

```
        ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).comment_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(commentPrompt + BLANK + commentText.getText(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

is called, commentText is not linkified (text at the bottom):

[image]

But when I change the code to the following:

```
((ViewHolder) viewHolder).comment_text.setText(commentText.getText());
```

The URLs do get linkified, but I lose the "Comment:" prompt:

[image]

How can I preserve the bold-faced prompt and still display live links?